# True or false: if $f\cdot g$ is continuous in $x_0$, then f and g are continuous in $x_0$ or f and g are not

Tags: functions, continuity

> True or false:
>
> 1. If $f\cdot g$ is continuous in $x_0$, then f and g are continuous in $x_0$ or f and g are not
> 2. If $f+g$ is continuous in $x_0$, then f and g are continuous in $x_0$ or f and g are not

I'm not quite sure about this question, tried to find an example to contradict this with no luck.
I tired to find two functions, f and g such that $f\cdot g$ is continuous but f is continuous and g is not in order that show it is not correct.

Comment: What have you tried? Writing them down in your post will help you to get answers faster, because people  will know where you are stuck etc etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: there was a small error in this the first time which I've now corrected.

The first is false, the second is true.

For the first example, let $f$ be any discontinuous function, and let $g$ be the $0$ function. The product is $0$, and only one of $f$ and $g$ are discontinuous.

To prove the second, Suppose that $f+g$ is continuous at $x_0$ but that one of them (without loss of any generality let's just say it's $f$) is discontinuous at $x_0$. Then for any epsilon, there is a $\delta$ so that $|x-x_0|< \delta$ implies that $|(f+g)(x) - (f+g)(x_0)| < \epsilon$.

Since $f$ is discontinuous, then for sufficiently small $\epsilon$ and any $\delta$, we can choose any $x$ and we still have $|f(x) - f(x_0)| > \epsilon$. On the other hand, there is a $\delta$ for $g$ corresponding to $\epsilon/2$. So taking the smaller of the two $\delta$s, we can now estiamte:

By the reverse triangle inequality, $$|f(x) + g(x) - f(x_0) - g(x_0)|\geq ||f(x) - f(x_0)| - |g(x) - g(x_0)|| \geq \epsilon - \epsilon/2 = \epsilon /2 $$

and this proves the sum is discontinuous.

Answer (score 2):

1. is false. Just regard any noncontinuous function $f$ and $g = 0$, then
   $$f\cdot g = 0,$$
   which is continuous.
2. is true. Assume that $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ and $g$ isn't. Then there exists for every $\epsilon > 0$ and every $\delta>0$ an $x_{\epsilon,\delta}$ such that $d(x_{\epsilon,\delta},x_0)<\delta$ and $|g(x_{\epsilon,\delta})-g(x_0)|\geq \epsilon$.

   \begin{align}
   |(f+g)(x_{\epsilon,\delta}) - (f+g)(x_0)|&=|f(x_{\epsilon,\delta}) - f(x_{\epsilon,\delta})+g(x_{\epsilon,\delta})-g(x_0)| \\
   &\geq \big| |g(x_{\epsilon,\delta})-g(x_0)| - |f(x_{\epsilon,\delta}) - f(x_{\epsilon,\delta})|\big| \\
   & \geq |g(x_{\epsilon,\delta})-g(x_0)| \geq \epsilon
   \end{align}

Comment: More simply, if $f$ and $h=f+g$ are continuous, then also $g=h-f$ is continuous.

Comment: Indeed, this is more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.**

For $(1)$ take $g=0$.

For $(2)$, the statement is the same as: "If $f$ or $g$ continuous at $x_0$ AND $f$ or $g$ discontinuous at $x_0$ THEN $f+g$ discontinuous at $x_0$" .

These hints must be enough.