# If f and g are functions such that f + g is continuous, does it follow that at least one of f or g must be continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

If $f$ and $g$ are functions such that $f + g$ is continuous, does it follow that at least one of $f$ or $g$ must be continuous?

I said **yes.**

*Proof by contradiction.* Suppose not, that is, suppose $f$ and $g$ are functions such that $f+g$ is continuous but neither $f$ or $g$ is continuous. $f+g$ is continuous at each point by definition of a continuous function. Thus $\forall x_0$ which are points of accumulation of $dom(f)\cap dom(g)$, $$\lim_{x\to x_0}(f(x)+g(x))=f(x_0)+g(x_0).$$ By the theorem of sums of function limits, $$\lim_{x\to x_0}(f(x)+g(x))=\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x) + \lim_{x\to x_0}g(x).$$ Because $f$ and $g$ are not continuous, $$\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)\ne f(x_0) \text{ and } \lim_{x\to x_0}g(x)\ne g(x_0)$$ for at least one $x_0$. But  $$\lim_{x\to x_0}(f(x)+g(x))=\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x) + \lim_{x\to x_0}g(x)=f(x_0)+f(x_0),$$ meaning $$\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x) = f(x_0) \text{ and } \lim_{x\to x_0}g(x) = g(x_0).$$ Therefore, we have a contradiction and if $f$ and $g$ are functions such that $f+g$ is continuous, at least one of $f$ or $g$ must be continuous.

---

I found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2577919/604136), but the answer did not seem to make sense to me. Does that mean it's either both $f$ and $g$ are continuous or neither are? Therefore, would it not follow that at least one of $f$ or $g$ must be continuous? How could I go about proving this?

Thanks!

Comment: Pick a $f$ that is not continuous, then $f + (-f)$ is always continuous?

Comment: This is trivially false, even for nonnegative $f$ and $g.$ Take $f$ to be zero on $(-\infty, 0)$ and one on $[0, \infty). $ Take $g$ to be one on $(-\infty, 0)$ and zero on $[0, \infty) . $ Then $f+g \equiv 1$ but neither function is continuous.

Comment: If any two of $f$, $g$ and $f+g$ are continuous then so is the third.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $f(x)$ a discontinuous function,for example, $f(x)=\begin{cases}1&x\in{\mathbb Q}\\0&x\notin\mathbb{Q}\end{cases}$.

Take $g(x)=-f(x)$. Then $f$ and $g$ are discontinuous at every point, but $f(x)+g(x)=0$ which is continuous.